# First Round the product prices and then calculate the total in cart and checkout?

Tags: price, totals, magento2.4.3.p1

I want to first round the product price upto 2 decimal and then calculate the total .
Right now first it calculate the total and then round the total upto 2 decimal points.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest changing the price of the product you add to the cart to the rounded price. Here how I would have it done.

Create an event for `checkout_cart_product_add_after`.

And this is the execution funtion of the event

```
public function execute(
        \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
    ) {
        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $quoteItem */
        $quoteItem = $observer->getQuoteItem();
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product */
        $product = $observer->getProduct();

        $quoteItem = ( $quoteItem->getParentItem() ? $quoteItem->getParentItem() : $quoteItem );
        $roundedPrice = round($product->getFinalPrice(),2);

       
        $quoteItem->setCustomPrice((float)$roundedPrice);
        $quoteItem->setOriginalCustomPrice((float)$roundedPrice);  
        $quoteItem->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
            
        
    }
```

Hope it helps.